# Update the yolov5 annotations ".txt" files of cropped images

Tags: python, image-processing, yolov5

I want to crop images which is already annotated for yolov5 format ".txt", but the coordinates will change on cropped so how can i update it and the image crop coordinate will also be one of the class in annotation .txt file. For example: there is two model i want to train first will just detect odometer and second will detect the digits in it so for second model first model will crop odometer image and send to second, therefore for training the second model i need this coordinates corrected. Because I already have full annotation ready and don't want to redo annotation on cropped images of like more than 2k images

Comment: How would you crop the image? Can you be more specific about that? Do you want to crop each detected object?

Comment: @Batselot,  i have odometer images which is already annotated of classes: (0-9) 10 classes + (decimal ) 1 class + (odometer) 1 class = Total 12 classes, so odometer contains all the class object in it, that's why i want to crop the odometer area as per its coordinated and update all other classes coordinates as per the cropped image and also remove the odometer class from .txt, cause its will be cropped.

Comment: Okay so you want to save the images of each cropped image and class right? I have an easy solution for you , yolov5 has a --save-crop flag you can use. But you have to remove the class from the txts by a sample code.

Comment: @Batselot so will the annotations i.e x,y coordinates in txt file of all images modify if doing? Please can you elaborate? Also I have to train yolov5 to detect digits i.e class (0-9 and decimal) only using cropped images

Comment: Why would you need those coordinates if you just get the cropped image? And no, txt file won't change in that manner.

Comment: I need to train the images to detect readings only.

Comment: Well one good way to implement it is to write a script that will write the size of the img you are using when cropped in the txt file. The yolov5 should see the whole image as a box. But there are a few things unspecific about your case.  Why would you want to crop the image? You should also give some background images in order to show the algorithm where you want to detect these cases? How will cropping the images help you?

Comment: Well, there is two model i want to train first will just detect odometer and second will detect the digits in it so for second model first model will crop odometer image and send to second, therefore for training the second model i need this coordinates corrected. Because I already have full annotation ready and don't want to redo annotation on cropped images of like more than 2k images...

Comment: And I wrote the code to do so but the coordinates i am not able to calculate correctly.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. Maybe editing the question like that and showing what you have done so far will also get you more help. Anyway,  you can give the complete image size for the cropped objects.

Comment: Yeah i just need to know how to correctly modify the coordinates, I am stuck on it for 2 days straight.

Comment: Save the cropped images, read the size and save them on a different directory like:
0: img.size[0],img.size[1],img.size[2]

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the comments, I think I can write that as an answer as well.

You can crop your images from yolov5 with --save-crop flag of yolov5. And then for the annotations, you can actually give out full image size as the bounding box sizes. I suggest you check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55930342/training-yolo-to-detect-my-custom-object-with-already-cropped-images) as well.